# cannot open source file asm/mmiowb.h

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUz0v.png)

```json
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-80/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-80-generic/include",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-80/arch/x86/include",
                "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include",
                "/usr/include/asm-generic"
            ],
```

this is my vscode config json.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Did you look for that file in your file system? Did you find it? Where did you find it? Is the path in the list of include paths? Why not? Please [edit] your questions with new information, don't add comments.

Comment: What is the full path of `mmiowb.h`? If it were (e.g.) `/foo/bar/baz/asm/mmiowb.h`, you'd need to add `/foo/bar/baz` to the include directory list